# Trying to make a circle image

Tags: javascript, html, css

This question has been asked many times before but I still can't seem to figure such a simple problem out.

I'm trying to take an image and make it into a circle but when I try to do this:

```
const styles = {
  profileImage: {
    padding: "5% 0",
    objectFit: "cover",
    display: "block",
    width: "10vh",
    height: "10vh",
    borderRadius: "50%",
    border: "1px solid white", 
    margin: "0 auto"
  }
}
```

My image still comes out looking like this:
[image]

The white border is what I'd like the dimensions to be but the actual photo gets cropped off for some reason. I would appreciate any pointers! Been pulling my hair out for this :-(

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried without the padding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is due to this line:

```
padding: "5% 0",
```

Try removing that line

Comment: wow thanks! that fixed it! How careless of me. I thought that `padding` would be the padding outside of the border but that's clearly not the case. Thanksfor your help! I'll accept this answer once I'm allowed to :-)

Comment: "margin" is going to be outside of the border, and "padding" inside the border..  glad that it helped!